# Special characters changing to "?" using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, replace

I am using shapefiles in Spanish that I'm using to build a database and the special characters are displayed as normal,  but as soon as I ran an operation on the layer these characters change to `?`.
I tried using field calculator to replace `?` with them but as soon as I save the edits it reverts back.

I'm using ArcMap. When I added the shapefile the attribute tables had the special characters without a problem byt when I preformed an operation such as Merge or Dissolve or any other analysis that would deal with attributes, it would change every special charterer to `?`. What I tried doing was using field calculator and replaced the `?` with `ñ` for example and it worked but when I saved the edits the `?` would return back as if I didn't replace them.

Comment: What happens if you run the field calculator outside of an edit session?

Comment: When I tried running the field calculator outside  the editing session the '?' was still there (as if I didn't ran an operation on the fields) even though in the Results tab the calculation is successful and no warning was issued.